# Why does .NET add an additional slash to the already existent slashes in a path?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I've noticed that C# adds additional slashes (`\`) to paths. Consider the path `C:\Test`. When I inspect the string with this path in the text visualiser, the actual string is `C:\\Test`.

Why is this? It confuses me, as sometimes I may want to split the path up (using `string.Split()`), but have to wonder which string to use (one or two slashes).

Comment: Jeffrey got it right.  Use the Text Visualizer in the debugger window.  Looks like a spyglass icon.  Click it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

.Net is not adding anything to your string here.  What your seeing is an effect of how the debugger chooses to display strings.  C# strings can be represented in 2 forms

- Verbatim Strings: Prefixed with an `@` sign and removes the need o escape `\\` characters
- Normal Strings: Standard C style strings where `\\` characters need to escape themselves

The debugger will display a string literal as a normal string vs. a verbatim string.  It's just an issue of display though, it doesn't affect it's underlying value.

Answer (score 18):

The `\\` is used because the `\` is an escape character and is need to represent the a single `\`.

So it is saying treat the first `\` as an escape character and then the second `\` is taken as the actual value.  If not the next character after the first `\` would be parsed as an escaped character.

Here is a list of available escape characters:

```
\' - single quote, needed for character literals
\" - double quote, needed for string literals
\\ - backslash
\0 – Null 
\a - Alert 
\b - Backspace 
\f - Form feed 
\n - New line 
\r - Carriage return 
\t - Horizontal tab 
\v - Vertical quote 
\u - Unicode escape sequence for character 
\U - Unicode escape sequence for surrogate pairs. 
\x - Unicode escape sequence similar to "\u" except with variable length.
```

**EDIT:** To answer your question regarding `Split`, it should be no issue.  Use `Split` as you would normally.  The `\\` will be treated as only the one character of `\`.

Answer (score 6):

Debugger visualizers display strings in the form in which they would appear in C# code. Since `\` is used to escape characters in non-verbatum C# strings, `\\` is the correct escaped form.

Comment: while this is the case I don't think thats why the debugger shows it like it does, it simply needs a way to be able to show control characters (just as c# needs a way to interpretate them)

Comment: @stefan - Yeah, I can't speculate about why the tools developers do any of the things they do.

Comment: @stefan: I think that's what Jeffrey is saying - the visualizer shows strings as they would be in code, and they include the control characters in code.

Comment: that is correct. Also have in mind it couldve been shown as a @-string instead. Iam considering shifting my +1 to -1 ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so the answers above are not wholly correct. As such I am adding my findings for the next person who reads this post.

You cannot split a string using any of the chars in the table above if you are reading said string(s) from an external source.

i.e,

```
string[] splitStrings = File.ReadAllText([path]).Split((char)7);
```

will not split by those chars. However internally created strings work fine.

i.e.,

```
string[] splitStrings = "hello\agoodbye".Split((char)7);
```

This may not hold true for other methods of reading text from a file. I am unsure as I have not tested with other methods. With that in mind, it is probably best not to use those chars for delimiting strings!

Comment: This only means that the strings you are reading from the external source do not contain the character `(char)7`. If those strings contain the literal sequence of characters `\a`, then of course that will not be translated into the character `(char)7`. The escape sequence `\a` only applies to the string literals written in the C# code. I am not aware of a language that would do differently.