# Reading a line from text file returns unwanted slash

Tags: c#

I have an app that reads a document for thousands of lines. There's a specific substring within this textfile that sometimes starts like this "12345"NNNNNNN. The problem is that whenever C# reads the line it gives me something akin to "\12345\"NNNNNN. I already tried the string.Replace(@"\", "") extension but its still returning the same value and not substituting anything to my surprise. Here's the code:

```
 maskList.AccountMask = @line.Substring(156, 40);
 maskList.AccountMask = maskList.AccountMask.Replace(@"\", "");
```

Returns this:
"\"492200\"NNNNNNNNNN

Any suggestions?

Comment: Its not really there, the string viewer is just escaping the quotes. Try printing it to the debug output or console, you'll see that the slashes are not really there.

Comment: I've been debugging this for 2 hours and... oh my God I just failed as a programmer. Hey, post that as solution at least, someone else may stumble with the same rock :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does .NET add an additional slash to the already existent slashes in a path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465923/why-does-net-add-an-additional-slash-to-the-already-existent-slashes-in-a-path)

Comment: No worries, even the best of us has spent hours debugging what should be very apparent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The debug view for strings escapes things that would normally be escaped in code. This means that things like inline quotes or real \'s will be escaped with a `\` (making quotes look like `\"` and single slashes look like `\\`).

These slashes are not in the actual string, they are only there in the text viewer. You can verify that by writing out the string to the console or the debug output. Your `string.Replace` didn't work because there was nothing to replace.

You can verify this with a very small console program:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = ((char)34) + "492200" + ((char)34) + "NNNNNNNNN";

    Console.WriteLine(s);

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Character 34 is the `"` character, so I constructed the string without using \'s to escape them in code. Setting a breakpoint at the `ReadKey` call and examining the variable `s` shows `"\"492200\"NNNNNNNNN"`, but the console prints out the string without the \'s:

[image: Missing Slashes]

You'll also notice that the string has been surrounded by quotes as well that are not part of the original string. Clicking on the little magnifying glass will bring up the "Text Visualizer" which shows the unescaped string:

[image: Text Visualizer]

Comment: You can also click the magnifying glass next to the text to see the unescaped version in a new window.

Comment: Yes, the text visualizer shows that, I'll update my answer.