# C# file readline has double back slashes reading a text file

Tags: c#

I get the answers in the following topic/question:

[Reading a line from text file returns unwanted slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212053/reading-a-line-from-text-file-returns-unwanted-slash)

the answer states:

> The debug view for strings escapes things that would normally be escaped in code. This means that things like inline quotes or real 's will be escaped with a \ (making quotes look like " and single slashes look like \).
>
> These slashes are not in the actual string, they are only there in the text viewer. You can verify that by writing out the string to the console or the debug output. Your string.Replace didn't work because there was nothing to replace.

The actual string shows ok without double back slashes showing in the Console and in debugger using the magnifier , but when I add it to a List collection of strings it contains the double back slashes.

```
var data = new List<string>();
if (File.Exists(textFile))
{                                
    // Read file using StreamReader. Reads file line by line
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(textFile))
    {
        string ln;
        while ((ln = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ln);
            data.Add(ln);    // <-----  contains double quotes
        }
        file.Close();
    
    }
}
```

the incoming file contains a lot of data from the mainframe.

I'm not expecting double quotes.   I'm using VS 2017.

Comment: Is it possible to also include an excerpt of the resulting file contents?

Comment: This code does not add or remove backslashes or quotes or anything else, period. Whatever you're seeing is most likely still the result of how your debugger is visualizing things -- note that the default text visualizer and the way `List` is visualized need not be the same. Also note that this code is functionally equivalent to `data = File.ReadLines(textFile).ToList()`.

Comment: Skip the `File.Exists()` check. It's not as helpful as you might think... so much so that you still need to be able to handle an exception if the `StreamReader()` construction fails anyway. Therefore you may as well put all your effort into the exception handler. This also performs better on average, because as slow as exception handling can be it's still much master than the extra disk I/O for the .Exists() check.

Comment: Also, might I point you to [the `File.ReadLines()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines)? It turns this whole thing into a one-liner.

Comment: Finally, you missed the whole point of the quoted answer. **You're still viewing the string in a debugger**, even after adding to a list, and so the extra slashes are expected in that view.

Comment: this is  partial file contents. what I'm getting,.  the string variable "ln" contains  "\"MDE \\u0002\\0\\0\\0H\\0\\0\\0\\\"\\u0002\\0\\0ä\\u0004\\0\\0MQSTR   ãÅÇÔÃâØ@ÔæÃÁ*<\\u0081ˆ[ý\\u0013HÜÅs9 \\f¤\\b\\u0001\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\b\\0\\0\\0ÿÿÿÿIH01TIDRIVER SAFETY                 20230127150522MWMPG4  MWHSS1

Comment: Again, you missed the point of the quoted answer. The debugger is lying to you. If you want us to take this seriously, show us the extra characters present somewhere other than a Visual Studio window.

Comment: Ar you running for statement of the year?: "I'm not expecting double quotes. I'm using VS 2017."  

Comment: I know the debugger is lying to me.  but the contents of what it shows adds to my collection.  So if it really does not contain \\, then why does it show in my collection of strings?  And my subsequent code is handling the list like it does contain double \\.

Comment: Because you're also using a debugger view to examine the string collection, and that view can also lie.

Comment: You don't show "your subsequent code", so it's impossible for anyone to tell. Again: this code will not change the number of quotes or backslashes from your input file to the string, no matter what else you're seeing. Given the contents of your string it *is* quite possible you shouldn't be reading this file as a text file at all, but that's another matter.

Comment: Jeroen Mostert
what is the alternative?

Comment: Ar you running for statement of the year?: "I'm not expecting double quotes. I'm using VS 2017."   good one!!

Comment: If the contents of this file are actually binary, you can try using `BinaryReader`. To do this proficiently you'll have to know the actual format of the data (as in, what the individual bytes mean and how long fields are).