# How to make file path in required format?

Tags: c#, file, path

I want to compare to images and have to make them first as a Bitmap.

```
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(file1);
```

file1 contains the path as a string in the following format:

```
C:\anyfile.jpg
```

But C# need to convert this in the following format:

```
C:\\anyfile.jpg
```

Is there any possibility to convert the string to the needed format?

Comment: If you look at the string in the debugger it will escape \ to \\ so in reality if you see \\ the string actually contains \ so your likely fine.

Comment: Are you seeing the last format in the debugger ? If so, it is just a way the debugger escapes the backslash

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465923/why-does-net-add-an-additional-slash-to-the-already-existent-slashes-in-a-path

Comment: You can add @ before the string, it's will ignore the \ char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be:

```
file1 = file1.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```