# Unescaping doesn't work with Json string in C#

Tags: c#, json, string

I have a little issue with a return value from a web service.
The web service send me json string but I don't know why, there's a backslash in front of every double quote, I know it's to escape the characters but I try to unescape my string and the backslash stay here.

I try to use String.Replace but when I put back my double quote, a new backslash is automatically added.

The string is in UTF-8.

I need an unescaped string because I transform the string on JObject and he don't work with the escaped string...

For example :

what I have :

```
"{\"status\":\"success\",\"profiles\":[{\"nodeHumanId\":78698,\"nodeId\":112890
```

what I want :

```
{"status":"success","profiles":[{"nodeHumanId":78698,"nodeId":112890
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: [This is the debugger showing you the backslashes, they aren't actually in the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465923/why-does-net-add-an-additional-slash-to-the-already-existent-slashes-in-a-path).

Comment: what does fiddler show, who is adding the escapes?

Comment: I've got the same issue, we store JSON as a string value inside of another JSON in one of our databases. I just deserialize the outer layer, then once again, deserialize the JSON that's in the field. Once it's deserialized to an object, it's a simple matter of `JObject.FromObject(obj).ToString()` and you have your unescaped string back...