# How to keep the new line in sqlite query?

Tags: c#, sqlite, newline

In my sqlite database I have a field of type "Text" and its content is `Test. \nTest`, when I do a query to load this field, I get `Test.\\nTest` and hence I lose the new line. Can I keep the new line when I query the field?

Here is my query code in C#:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(string qry, object[] args) where T : new()
    {
        lock (_dbLock)
        {
            return DbConn.Query<T>(qry, args).ToList<T>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is it stored in the sqlite database. Is it a literal `\\n` (as if it was escaped before it was INSERTed?)

Comment: In database I see it is "Test. \nTest"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does .NET add an additional slash to the already existent slashes in a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465923/why-does-net-add-an-additional-slash-to-the-already-existent-slashes-in-a-path)