# Replace "\\" with "\" in WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

Tags: c#, string, replace

I want to store the `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` in a `string` but with only  one `\`.

How can I achieve this?

I tried `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Replace(@"\\", @"\")`

Comment: Isn't that a very bad idea? ` \ ` just means to escape the next character as a literal, so ` \\ ` translates to a single literal ` \\ `. And apparently also messes up comment formatting quite badly.

Comment: @Artem then please provide me a solution. replace doesn't work.

Comment: There should already only be one '\'. Maybe you're misinterpreting your debugging tools showing '\\' because in the underlying string it's not a escape sequence '\' but a real '\' character? Or is there really a double '\' when e.g. `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` is written to a file?

Comment: @DavidWalser if you call Console.WriteLine you'll see Replace working

Comment: @DavidWalser can you provide your WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

Comment: thanks a lot @The-First-Tiger didn't know that :/

Comment: yes it is @Liam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should already only be one '\'. You're misinterpreting your debugging tools showing '\' because in the underlying string is not a escape sequence '\' but a real '\' character.

Also see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465923/why-does-net-add-an-additional-slash-to-the-already-existent-slashes-in-a-path) for some reference.

When using Visual Studio [the Text Visualizer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/09/23/did-you-know-how-to-use-the-text-visualizer-319/) also can help. It will show the 'real' text.

Comment: thanks a lot :) I really didn't know that! (Also thanks to the others for downvoting ;) )

Comment: The correct thing to do here is to flag this as a duplicate not add an answer that essentially points at that duplicate question. Please read [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

Comment: Sure. "If understanding why the questions are at all related requires a detailed explanation, the questions aren't duplicates, merely related." From the *questioners perspective* it had nothing to do with ".net adding some extra characters". He simply didn't know this aspect and therefore wasn't able to search for it and needed an explanation. I didn't consider this a duplicate and the link was for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

Comment: No this is not working, you also need @""

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `Replace()` function on string to manipulate the character \

```
var foo = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Replace("\\\\","\\");
```

Note as this is the character used to escape unusual characters you will need to put `\\` for each `\`

Or you can prefix the replace string with the `@`

```
var foo = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

Comment: oh god please use @"\\" instead of "\\\\"