# C# equivalent of "%r"%stringName in python. Convert regular string to verbatim string

Tags: c#, string

Here's my problem:

```
string a = "example\file\path.here";
```

If I want to split this string on the '\' character it doesn't work because this is an escape character so I have to use:

```
string a = @"example\file\path.here";
```

And then I can split it and work with it. The problem is, I'm getting the file path string value from a sql server query and storing it in a string variable so I can't declare the "@" in front of it.

For example:

```
string a = MyQueryToStringFunction(connectionString,"SELECT Path FROM TestTable");
```

Print(a) will print "example\file\path.here" format.

I saw in python you can just use "%r"%stringName to convert from regular string to raw (which is equivalent to verbatim in C# if I'm not mistaken).

Question: Is there a way to convert regular string variable to verbatim string in C#?

Comment: You don't need the `@` for anything other than string literals *in your code*. It does not change "processing mode" of the string (it does not exist to begin with). It changes the way the compiler reads *your code*, not the way the program reads the memory that holds the string.

Comment: you issue is that the sql string has / not \. nothing to do with @ or escapes or anything

Comment: show us code that is failing to split the string

Comment: Thanks guys. I got it working. I'm fairly new to C# and was confusing myself. When playing with the C# Interactive terminal the string would print with single "\" chars format but when debugging I realized they were represented as \\. Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does .NET add an additional slash to the already existent slashes in a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5465923/11683)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys. I got it working. I'm fairly new to C# and was confusing myself. When playing with the C# Interactive terminal the string would print with single "\" chars format but when debugging I realized they were represented as "\\".