# Use date as a filepath

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I need the following filepath according to date:

> yyyy\MM\d

and I though I could it in one call to DateTime class like this:

```
string filepath = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"yyyy\MM\d");
```

However, it yields: 
"2018M11d" which is wrong.

Is there a way to escape the backwards slahes?

Comment: I think the filesystem can't use \ as part of the filename

Comment: Isn't a backslash a [forbidden file name character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars)? ([Example fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KlzLdQ))

Comment: It is, rather replace the blackslashes with dots, it would still make sense as a data

Comment: Do you want this output 2018\11\22

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can.

```
string filepath = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"yyyy\\MM\\d");
```

Comment: No it doesn't @kalle31. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465923/why-does-net-add-an-additional-slash-to-the-already-existent-slashes-in-a-path

Comment: In a file _name_ yes. Not in a file path @UweKeim.

Answer (score 4):

The safest way is to split the date in its individual components and then use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine):

```
var dateParts = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy MM d").Split(' ');
var filePath = Path.Combine(dateParts);
```

This isolates you from the underlying filesystem details you aren't really concerned about (i.e. which character is used as the directory separator).

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

This will help you.