# When I serialize an html tag I get <\/b> in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am forming the following example string.

```
<b> ..... </b>.
```

```
foreach (var paragraphType in orderCommentPieces)
{
    switch (paragraphType.PresentationType)
    {
        case enumPresentationType.Highlighted:
            textParagraph.Append("<b>");
            textParagraph.Append(paragraphType.Text);
            textParagraph.Append("</b>");
            break;

        case enumPresentationType.Quote:
            textParagraph.Append("<q>");
            textParagraph.Append(paragraphType.Text);
            textParagraph.Append("</q>");
            break;
        default:
            textParagraph.Append(paragraphType.Text);
            break;
    }
    businessRationalesData.Text = textParagraph.ToString();
    businessRationales.BusinessRationalesList.Add(businessRationalesData);
}
```

When I return from the service when serializing and deserializing I get the following

```
<b> ... <\ / b>.
```

How could I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: I get this. A empresa <b>não apresenta capitais próprios adequados<\/b>

Comment: It looks like some code is trying to escape the forward-slash, which usually doesn't need that. What happens to the text between the code you showed and where you see the result?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Are you viewing your string [with a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466227/11683)?

Comment: Is `textParagraph` a `StringBuilder`? Provide more details.