# Byte [] to int conversion impossible

Tags: c#

And the problem I have, when converting `Byte[]` to `String`, I tried with the `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` and the `ncoding.Ascii.GetString` but nothing changes ???

I always end up with a string that has backslashes in this form

```cs
sRecv = "\\0\\0\\0u0001"
```

I don't understand....

Sender code

```cs
public void SendDatas(int progress)
{
    byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(progress);
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        Array.Reverse(intBytes);
    byte[] result = intBytes;
    try
    {
        _socketClient.Send(result, SocketFlags.None);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Erreur lors de la transmition des données", "Erreur", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

receive code

```cs
public int EcouterReseau(Socket socketClient)
{

    string sRecv;
    try
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int recv = socketClient.Receive(data);
        sRecv = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, recv);
    }
    catch
    {
        sRecv = "0";
    }
    int returnValue = int.Parse(sRecv.Remove(0, 7));
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: What kind of result do you expect to get from converting an `int` into an array of four bytes, and then treating that array as a UTF-16 encoded string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does .NET add an additional slash to the already existent slashes in a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465923/why-does-net-add-an-additional-slash-to-the-already-existent-slashes-in-a-path)

Comment: An integer value is not a string. It's not made of characters. An `int` in .NET is 32 bits wide, that's 4 bytes (32 = 4 * 8). These 4 bytes combined are an `int` value. These 4 bytes are still not a string nor are they characters. They are just the 32 bits of an `int` value.